# go ipfs node access files from js ipfs browser node?

Tags: ipfs, js-ipfs

I have two ipfs nodes. One js-ipfs node running in the browser and one go-ipfs node. Each node is running on separate hardware. The nodes are not directly connected. I'm having trouble access files added on the js-ipfs node from the go-ipfs node. Is this possible today? If so, what do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Hey Bob did you get an access to go-ipfs server from ipfs-http-clinet ? I am struggeling with the same thing.